# Express Rewriting for Clean URLs in MEAN Stack Application with no index.html

Tags: angularjs, .htaccess, express, url-rewriting, mean-stack

Like many other clean angular URL rewrites, upon refreshing the page on a clean URL like `localhost:3000/profile` I get the `GET /profile 404` error. I have been trying to use an Express Rewrite to send the `index.html` file, but as far as I know, I don't have an `index.html` to send, as it's not rendered until the `index.js` route.

I tried the following in my `app.js`:

```
app.all('/*', function(req, res, next) {
    // Just send the index.html for other files to support HTML5Mode
    res.sendFile('index.html', { root: __dirname });
});
```

and receive `Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat 'C:\xampp\htdocs\healthyu\healthyu\index.html'`

My directory looks like [this image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t3hs2.jpg), and I can see there is no index.html file in the root directory. I have tried `views/index.html`, `views/index.ejs`, and `views/index` with no luck, and `views/index.ejs` actually prompted a [download when I refreshed the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yNVjg.jpg).

Is there a way to use Express to successfully rewrite the URLs, or will I be more successful with a mod-rewrite in an `.htaccess` file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what I needed to do was change all of my server requests that were API requests to use the `/api` prefix, so `get /api/posts` in order to reduce conflicts with  `get /posts` which was the original API call and view name along with other conflicts.

My `index.html` is generated in my express `routes/index.js` file so I just needed to make sure I used that file whenever I tried to navigate to a different URL than the home entry point. The relevant parts of the code looked like the following:

```js
var index = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');

app.use('/', index);
app.use('/api', index);
app.use('/users', users);

app.use("/*", index);
```